# Error in function that returns 3 values

Tags: c++, c++17, auto

I am using a function that returns 3 values using tuples in C++17.

The program is

```
void test_noisy()
{

  s4prc::Noisy<s4prc::StrVec> big{s4prc::makeStrVec(10'000)};
  std::cout << ">>> big=" << big << '\n';

 s4prc::Noisy<std::string> evenStr;

 s4prc::Noisy<std::string> oddStr;
int  totalLength;
  auto [evenStr, oddStr, totalLength]=s4prc::manyResults(big);
 }
```

When I compile, I obtain this error :

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
  auto [evenStr, oddStr, totalLength]=s4prc::manyResults(big);
    ^
 GNUmakefile:192 : la recette pour la cible « prog.o » a échouée
```

Thanks,

Younès

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and are you sure you're compiling on a C++17 compiler?

Comment: I don't think any of the big compilers have C++17 enabled by default.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, they didn't, they recently switched to C++14 as default. Probably will last a couple of years.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Really, that's fast though, C++14 already as default. I remember 11 took ages.

Comment: @Sombrero At least GCC and clang have. MSVC too I think. I can imagine, I wasn't there when C++14 was finished, not to mention C++11 which never got to be the default.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's the only problem but... with

```
s4prc::Noisy<std::string> evenStr;
s4prc::Noisy<std::string> oddStr;
int  totalLength;
auto [evenStr, oddStr, totalLength]=s4prc::manyResults(big);
```

you're defining and **redefining** `evenStr`, `oddStr` and `totalLength`. This should give a compilation error.

Try deleting the first definitions (the three rows before `auto`).

Second: are you sure you're compiling C++17?

Comment: Even if I delete the declarations of evenStr and oddStr, I still get the same error.

Comment: @RAOUIYounès - so there is another error; are you sure you're compiling C++17?

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I find is to use make_tuple in the return of the definition of the function;

```
return std::make_tuple(std::move(even),    // std::move() prevents from
      std::move(odd),     // copying existing locals
      std::move(length)); // to tupl
```

Besides, when calling the function use : 
       auto data=s4prc::manyResults(big);
and get the three compounents of data with :

```
  std::cout << ">>> evenStr=" << std::get<0>(data) << '\n';
  std::cout << ">>> oddStr=" << std::get<1>(data) << '\n';
  std::cout << ">>> totalLength=" << std::get<2>(data) << '\n';
```

Comment: This can solve your problem but isn't an answer to your question. You're using the C++11/C++14 way to manage tuples returned by a function. C++17 introduce structured binding declaration but you have an error using it. I suspect (and not only I) that you're not compiling your code with flags to activate C++17 support.